# Why do some relationship merge queries fail in Neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, py2neo

I set up a Neo4j instance (3.2) both on my local machine (with `brew`) and on a remote machine (with Docker). I'm trying to run a query, for which I use `py2neo` functions (`merge` on the relationship) which create the Cypher automatically.

I define two `Node` objects, one each for `subject` and `object` labels with `entity` as the property for both. I create a `Relationship` object with the relationship type (`is cheaper according to` in the query below) and add a property called `confidence` to this relationship type. This is the query I'm trying to run:

```
MERGE (a0:subject {entity:"VSS"})
SET a0:subject
MERGE (a1:object {entity:"Vanguard"})
SET a1:object
MERGE (a0)-[r0:`is cheaper according to`]->(a1) 
SET r0.confidence="1.0"
RETURN a1, a0, r0 LIMIT 1
```

This query works fine on my local Neo4j, but on the remote, I get the following error:

```
bolt.fetch S: FAILURE {u'message': u'Could not create token', u'code': u'Neo.DatabaseError.General.UnknownError'}
```

I tried running the above query directly in the browser client too, and had the same response, viz. it works on my local Neo4j but not my remote.

Further, if I replace the relationship type `is cheaper according to` with just `is cheaper`, the query fails both in my local and my remote Neo4j.

My setup for Neo4j on both is identical and pretty vanilla. I do have two indexes on each though, on the `subject` and `object` nodes.

I couldn't find anything to support differing behavior on the local v/s the remote, and I certainly couldn't see any reason why changing the relationship type would fail. Is there something I'm missing here?

Would really appreciate the help, thanks!

Comment: Not sure I completely understand. So you claim that the above with MERGE (a0)-[r0:`is cheaper`]->(a1) ... fails both locally and remotely using the Neo4j browser (not py2neo) ? Seems to work fine (and idempotent) for me. P.S. Stackoverflow is formatting with backticks, there are obviously backticks around "is cheaper".

Comment: This does not answer your question, but: the first 2 `SET` clauses should be removed, as they are just setting labels that already exist.

Comment: do you see any detailed error in the log files? There should be a nested error?

Comment: Which exact version do you have? I tried it with 3.2.0 and 3.2.3 and worked in both cases.